# Upper bound of a sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation

How can I find a tight upper bound for the following expression:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} a_i \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{i} \frac{1}{b_j} =  a_1 \frac{1}{b_1} + a_2 (\frac{1}{b_1} + \frac{1}{b_2}) + \dots + a_k (\frac{1}{b_1} + \frac{1}{b_2} \dots \frac{1}{b_k})$

where,
$b_1 \geq b_2 \geq \dots \geq b_k$, $\forall i ~ a_i, b_i > \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $b_i\geqslant b_k$, $ \frac{1}{b_j}\leqslant  \frac{1}{b_k}$ hence
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} a_i \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{i} \frac{1}{b_j}  \leqslant  \frac{1}{b_k}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} ia_i.$$
This is tight if all the $b_i$ are equal.

Comment: Yeah, if all $b_i$'s  are equal, this is good. But, It would be great if we can do anything better considering all $b_i$'s are not equal?